# Multiple RESTful API-s in one Swagger for Tyk

Tags: json, rest, swagger, tyk

I have 2 different restful api-s, and I would like to use Tyk for gateway.

My plan is to have a common url (like: http://viktorservices) which can towards messages to those two api endpoints.

For example, the first api is a user manager api, and has an endpoint:

```
GET: http://localhost:8080/usermanager/users
```

And the other api is a car manager api, and it's endpoint:

```
GET: http://localhost:8081/carmanager/cars
```

Is it possible somehow, to upload a Swagger JSON for the Tyk Catalog (For developer portal) to be able to se only one API called: *User and Car Manager*?

And when I click on "View Documentation" in Tyk's developer site, all of the endpoints from both APIs are visible, grouped by their main API names?

I tried to put the two swagger jsons into one as an array, but then it is not visible on the Developer Site.

I am able to upload the swaggers one by one, but then I will have two API-s on the Dev site of Tyk.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main point here is that developer portal documentation/swagger does not have to correlate with the actual APIs you have. Portal gets organized by catalogues/policies. So you can have multiple internal Tyk APIs, but expose them as the single catalog in Portal, by creating Policy which gives access to both APIs. So, just create new "public" swagger file for documentation purpose, which includes endpoints from both of your internal APIs.

Does it make sense?